# Row with maximum 1's TLE Problems

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to solve the TLE problem in this code below--
in this code getting TLE error on run time how I can solve this please tell explain

```
int t=sc.nextInt();
        while(t>0)
        {
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            int m=sc.nextInt();
            int [][]a=new int[n][m];
            
            int row=0;
            
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
                {
                    a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                }
            }
            int i=0;
            int j=m-1;
            while(i<n&&j>=0)
            {
                if(a[i][j]==1)
                {
                    row=i;  
                }
                else
                    i++;
            }
            System.out.print(row);
            t--;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because whenever `a[i][j]==1`, you are not moving ahead to the next column (`(j-1)-th` column). That's why your program gets stuck there. It repeatedly keeps checking the same value (`a[i][j]`) which is 1.
The below modification is needed to get the correct result:

```java
if (a[i][j] == 1)
{
    row = i;
    --j;
}
else 
    ++i;
```